# Number of graphs with given degree and vertices.

Tags: graph-theory, permutations, combinations

I'm not a Mathematician. I'm a programmer and i found a question on graph theory.
I have a simple undirected graph with vertices N say 6. Now i want to find total number of solution for given degree. say i have degrees (1,2,3,4,5,5) for given set of vertices (A,B,C,D,E,F) than print total number of solution.

Comment: I doubt that there's a formula for this. You could write a computer program to do an exhaustive search, I don't know whether you can do any better. But for your example, the answer is zero. $E$ and $F$ must join all the others, but then each vertex has degree at least 2.

Comment: It's jut an example, what i'm asking is if there is some value like One vertex say A has degree 3 than how many different solution are there for this configuration.

Comment: Sounds like you need to list all graphs for a degree sequence (if there are any). Can your results be isomorphic? Do you really need to list them, or can you use a library of pre-built graphs and filter out by degree sequence?

Comment: No the result is Non- isomorphic. Actually Question is like this i have been given two integers N Vertices and K. Now suppose N = 2 and K = 3 than than The cost of the graph with a single edge is 1^3+1^3 = 2. 
The cost of the graph with no edges is 0^3+0^3 = 0. So the final answer is 2+0 = 2.

Comment: You're saying that the cost $k$ is associated with the degree of a vertex, and not an edge since you're doubling $e^k$, where e is the number of edges?

Comment: Yes, Edges/degrees. for N = 2 vertex there are only two ways either they are connected with one edge or not connected. So if they are connected than both have degree/edges 1, So Ans. is 1^3 + 1^3 = 2.  Now the second way is they are not connected so 0^3 + 0^3 = 0. Total = 2+0 = 2.